# Можно ли в ModX Revo использовать плейсхолдеры в поле контента у ресурса?

Tags: modx

Плейсхолдеры - прекрасная штука. Но вот можно ли в ModX Revo использовать плейсхолдеры в поле контента у ресурса? Если да, то как?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если в настройках не ставили ограничение, тогда можно использовать:

```
[[*pagetitle]]
```